# How can I find out if my user has an admin permission?

Tags: php, database, session, admin

I'm currently coding a blog to get experience with php in which I can log in. In the table:

```
user( id, username, password, permission)
```

there is one user that has the permission "admin", every other user has the permission "normal".

I want that only an admin can edit posts, so I need to find out what permission the currently logged in user has. I tried to do it with Sessions, but somehow I didn't manage to get it work.

This is the query in the `UserRepository.php` in which I interact with the db

```
public function isAdmin($username)
{
  $table = $this->getTableName();
  $model = $this->getModelName();

  $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT `permission` FROM `{$table}` WHERE username = :username");
  $stmt->execute(['username' => $username]);

  $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, $model);
  $isAdmin = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_CLASS);

  return $isAdmin;
}
```

Here is the part of a function from the `LoginService.php` in which I call the upper function in the repository:

```
public function attempt($username, $password)
{
  $user = $this->userRepository->findByUsername($username);

  if (password_verify($password, $user->password)) { 
  if ($this->userRepository->isAdmin($user->username) == "admin") {
    $_SESSION['admin'] = "admin";
  }
  $_SESSION['login'] = $user->username;            
  session_regenerate_id(true);                    
  return true;                                      
}
```

This is a part of the `__construct` in the `PostsAdminController.php` in which I'm trying to get the value of the permission of the logged in user and save it into the session if it is "admin" and not "normal":

```
$username = $_SESSION['login'];
$permission = $this->userRepository->isAdmin($username);

if ($permission == "admin") {
  $_SESSION['admin'] = $permission;
```

I also have a part of the header, because for admins there is a different navigation as for normal user.

```
<?php if(!empty ($_SESSION['login'])):?>
  <div class="logged-in-user">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">
        <a href="http://localhost:8888/blog/public/index.php/dashboard">
          <?php echo e($_SESSION['login']);?>
        </a>
      </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <?php if ($_SESSION['admin'] == "admin"): ?>
        <a href="http://localhost:8888/blog/public/index.php/dashboard">
          dashboard
        </a>
```

This won't give me the dashboard for both, the admin and the normal user. But if I ask if it's set:

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['admin'])): ?>
```

Then it shows the dashboard in the dropdown-navigation for both again...

**I don't know why it doesn't work, so how do I correctly find out the permission of the logged in user and show them different things based on their permission?**

Comment: `$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_CLASS);` will return `array("permission" => "admin")` - so you should do `return $isAdmin['permission'];` (Or you can do `$stmt->fetchColumn();`)

Comment: Also, here it looks like you are passing the permission? `isAdmin($user->permission)`, shouldn't that be the username?

Comment: you're right, I corrected it. But it still doesn't work

Comment: You should update the code in your question with the corrections you did, so we know we are working from the same place, especially because there are no answers yet.

Comment: If you say "it still doesn't work" please can you show us your PHP error reports. (in your question, not in comments)

Comment: do you really have a function called `e`? How descriptive `:-p`

Comment: @Martin It's probably an output sanitizer of some kind

Comment: @Martin 1.) e stands for entities (htmlentities)  2.) I don't get an error, it just still shows the dashboard when both user are logged in

Comment: If the problem persists, use your IDE or use `print_r(...)` or `error_log(...)` to output data values at each step of the logic to see where the values are becoming unexpected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks easier simply for you to return a boolean for your function; rather than a string value,then you can use your function in comparisons with relative ease (see bottom of answer).

```
/***
 * Function for finding out if user is an admin
 * @param string $username 
 * @return bool isAdmin? 
 ***/
public function isAdmin($username)
{
  $table = $this->getTableName();
  $model = $this->getModelName();

  if(empty($username)){
     return false;
  }

  $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT `permission` FROM `{$table}` WHERE username = :username");
  $stmt->execute(['username' => $username]);

  $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, $model);
  $isAdminResult = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_CLASS); 

  if($isAdminResult['permission'] === "admin"){ 
      // YES this user is marked as an admin. 

      // You can also if you wish, save the admin details to a @_SESSION here
      // $_SESSION['admin'] == "admin";
      return true;
  }

  // No this user is not admin 
  return false;

}
```

Then in your later code (in the `PostsAdminController` construct, for example):

```
if($this->userRepository->isAdmin($username)){
    // $_SESSION['admin'] = "Yeeeaahhh";
    // whatever you want to run for admins only. 
}
```

It's smoother and easier to compare the `$_SESSION['admin']` value than to repeatedly run a database and class method call.

Comment: How can I put the if into the PostsAdminController? In the __Construct like I did before? The repository is only for the querys and nothing else, this is what the controllers are for

Comment: @ofmiceandmoon my `later code:...` block is taken from your question referencing the `PostsAdminController` construct . Therefore this code change should be obvious?

Comment: Ah I interpreted it as the codes I should put in the header when asking if the logged in user has the admin permission, my bad sorry

Comment: @ofmiceandmoon no worries - I have updated my answer.

Comment: And how can I achieve that  `if ($isAdmin['permission'] === "admin" { ... " in the isAdmin()-function in the `userRepository` is in the `PostsAdminController`? I'm asking because I seperated the db interaction so that the querys have their own file (kinda)

Comment: and I did it just like you but it still doesn't work

Comment: I honestly don't know how to do that or where to put the error log. I am completely new in this world of programming

Comment: I var_dumped the $_SESSION['admin'] and logged in with both users, both were stated as admin

Comment: Then with the greatest respect, you need to learn to stand before you can try running. Please review [how to read PHP errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display) and many similar questions on Stack Overflow

Comment: Also you said above that you had no errors from your PHP error logs, and now you say you don't know how to read errors from the logs.... We can't help you without your help.

Comment: the thing is, aren't the error messages get written in a file? I didn't install the ide, for e.g. the htdocs folder is empty

Comment: When you log out a user or when you log in again you should clear your users session data by doing . `$_SESSION = [];` Because even if a user logs out the session data remains the same unless set otherwise.

Comment: PHP error messages are written to a file as defined in the `php.ini` core. On a new page set: [`phpinfo();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) and read the (large) output and find `error_log` to see where on your system PHP is putting the error logs. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you, and sorry for probably make you cry because I don't know much :D $_SESSION[] solved the Problem.

Comment: @ofmiceandmoon hahaha, no worries at all. Glad to get the problem fixed. Crying is all part of the game `;-)`